# DataTables plugin Cannot read JSON data coming from localstorage

Tags: json, datatables

**QUESTION**:
I don't understand why the 'contentType' parameter cannot be found. I have it spelled correctly. I'm assuming I'm not setting the parameters correctly.  The information in the support link did not help.  My guess is that I'm not referencing the object correctly.

Any ideas?

**ERROR**:
DataTables warning: table id=attachment - Requested unknown parameter 'contentType' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

**JSON**:

```
[{
"_data$p$0": {
    "id": "AAMkADU4MzkxN2RmLTdiZS53ao=",
    "name": "somefile.xlsx",
    "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "size": 43069,
    "attachmentType": 0,
    "isInline": false
}}]
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    app.initialize();
    window.alert = function (message) { app.showNotification("DataTable", message); };



    var attachments = localStorage.getItem("Attachments");


    console.log(attachments);
    // Display Table
    $('#attachment').DataTable({
        data: attachments,
        columns: [
            { data: 'contentType' },
            { data: 'name' }
        ]
    });

});};
```

**HTML**:

```
<table id="attachment" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>                      
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do two things.  Individually, neither worked.

1. Set the **data** option to a JSON object and not just a JSON string
2. Use the dot notation to reference each element.

Here is the working code

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    app.initialize();
    window.alert = function (message) { app.showNotification("DataTable", message); };


    // The value in localStorage was set with JSON.Stringify
    // Now I make it a JSON object once again
    var attachments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Attachments"));


    // Display Table
    $('#attachment').DataTable({
        data: attachments,
        columns: [
            { data: '_data$p$0.contentType' }, //Dot notation to reference the elements
            { data: '_data$p$0.name' }
        ]
    });

});
 };
```